# Testing Django view with environment variables

Tags: django, unit-testing

I am starting to write tests for a Django app, which relies on several environment variables.  When I am testing it in the shell, I can import os and specify the variables and my tests work just fine.  However, when I put them into tests.py, I still get a key error because those variables are not found.  here's what my test looks like:

```
from django.utils import unittest
from django.test.utils import setup_test_environment
from django.test.client import Client
import os

os.environ['a'] = 'a'
os.environ['b'] = 'b'


class ViewTests(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        setup_test_environment()

    def test_login_returning_right_template(self):
        """ get / should return login.html template """
        c = Client()
        resp = c.get('/')
        self.assertEqual(resp.templates[0].name, 'login.html')
```

Is this the wrong place to initialize those variables?  I tried to do it on setUp, but with the same result - they are not found.  Any suggestions on how to initialize environment variables before running a test suite?
Thanks!
Luka

Comment: Your problem source is that relying on os.envior in views is bad thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not relay on os.envior in your views. If you have to, do It in your settings.py

```
MY_CUSTOM_SETTING = os.environ.get('a', 'default_value')
```

And in views use settings variable:

```
from django.conf.settings import MY_CUSTOM_SETTING
print MY_CUSTOM_SETTING
```

Then in your test you can set this setting:

```
from django.test import TestCase

class MyTestCase(TestCase):

    def test_something(self):
        with self.settings(MY_CUSTOM_SETTING='a'):
            c = Client()
            resp = c.get('/')
            self.assertEqual(resp.templates[0].name, 'login.html')
```

Comment: Just curious, which version of Django are you using?  Mine (1.3.0) fails on django.conf.settings.  I can still do form django.conf import settings, though.

Comment: I have not tested that, that was only idea. In fact it should fail on that one.

Comment: new versions of django you can't import individual custom settings  you have to import all of them.
from django.conf import settings

Comment: I agree with Fabian. For me, from django.conf.settings import xyz didn't work. I had to do from django.conf import settings

Comment: django.conf.settings isn’t a module – it’s an object. You can not do django.conf.settings import MY_CUSTOM_SETTING